# Migrate maven dependencies to gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, cucumber

I start with software testing - using Cucumber, Java, gradle.
I try to learn this with the book "The Cucumber for Java Book"

But I try to do I with gradle instead of maven... But now I have some problems...
I stick on page 149. I have to give so dependecies:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
<version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I try to "translate" this to gradle

```
dependencies {
     testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
     testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:2.4.0'
     testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:2.4.0'
     testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-picocontainer', version: '1.2.5'
     compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-webapp', version: '9.4.12.v20180830'
}
```

Is this right?
**compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-webapp', version: '9.4.12.v20180830'**

After that I have to run:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="nicebank.AtmServer"
```

But how can I do this with gradle?

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: the dependency for `jetty-webapp` looks OK (but you should replace `compile` by `implementation` if you use latest version of Gradle). And for running the app you could use `JavaExec` task from the Gradle Java Plugin, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick comment :)

But I dont really know how I can configurate the JaceExec task for my project :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the dependency for jetty-webapp seems OK but you should use `implementation` instead of `compile` ( `compile` has been deprecated, see [Java dependency configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations)):

```
implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-webapp', version: '9.4.12.v20180830'
```

or

```
implementation "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.4.12.v20180830"
```

For the equivalent of "maven exec:java" in Gradle , you could use the [Gradle JavaExec task type](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html):  try to define a task in your build as follows:

```
task runApp(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

    main = 'nicebank.AtmServer'

}
```

(not tested, you migth have to adapt it) , and run it with

```
gradle runApp
```

You could alternatively use **Gretty** plugin to run your webapp (no need to define your own JavaExec task in this case), as documented [here](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-web-applications/#add_the_code_gretty_code_plugin_and_run_the_app) and [here](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/):

```
plugins{
    // your existing plugins   
    id "org.gretty" version "2.2.0"
}
```

You can then run the application with:

```
gradle appRun
```

Answer (score 2):

Your dependency looks good. Just one note: consider using `implementation` over `compile` as it improves the performance. Read about `compile` deprecation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation).

You can also put your properties in `gradle.properties` file and reference them in the build script:

*gradle.properties*:

```
jettyVersion=9.4.12.v20180830
```

*build.gradle*:

```
implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-webapp', version: jettyVersion
```

Jetty team also published [BOMs](https://hackernoon.com/maven-bill-of-materials-dependency-b6eb88f5c188): — [`org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-bom:9.4.12.v20180830`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-bom/9.4.12.v20180830/pom) in your case. If you use multiple projects of the same version you can [import the BOM](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:bom_import) and skip the version completely:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-bom:9.4.12.v20180830'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-runner'
}
```

As for the "exec" task: if you have only one main class in your project, like `nicebank.AtmServer`, consider using Gradle's [Application Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html):

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

mainClassName = 'nicebank.AtmServer'
```

This way you don't need to create "exec" task manually, you'll get one (`run`) from the plugin. As a bonus you'll get two "distribution" tasks that will create a ready-for-distribution archive with your app: `distZip` and `distTar`.